# error in my postgresql syntax (%) sign

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geoserver

hi im following this tutorial http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/tutorial-routing/ of which im now in the part where i need to make an sql view for the shortest path.
but ive been into postgresql for a few months.
but i cant seem to understand the purpose of the Percent(%) signs on the attached code snippet below.
ive looked around for it but ive only seen things talking about this :: and less on % signs.
anyway here is the snippet. cause i cant seem to make it run.

```
SELECT

  min(r.seq) AS seq,
  e.old_id AS id,
  e.name,
  e.type,
  e.oneway,
  sum(e.time) AS time,
  sum(e.distance) AS distance,
  ST_Collect(e.the_geom) AS geom
FROM
  pgr_dijkstra(
   'SELECT
    id,
    source::INT4,
    target::INT4,
    %cost% AS cost,
    CASE oneway
      WHEN ''yes'' THEN -1
      ELSE %cost%
    END AS reverse_cost
  FROM edges_noded', %source%, %target%, true) AS r,
  edges_noded AS e
WHERE
  r.id2 = e.id
GROUP BY
  e.old_id, e.name, e.type, e.oneway
```

its a postgresql code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are placeholders used by GeoServer during creation of view. They will be replaced by whatever you input in said application.

If you aren't using GeoServer, then maybe try using his earlier example with hardcoded values:

```
%cost% -> time
%source% -> 753
%target% -> 756
```

or later:

```
%cost% -> time
%source% -> 100
%target% -> 1000
```

Unrelated, but doing JOINs by comma separating tables in FROM clause and then listing conditions in WHERE is outdated and not recommended.

Comment: thanks for the answer sir. much appreciated. seems like i had to read a lil bit more.. shame on me. thanks again sir.